# Order By the result of an expression on each result / User-Generated Meta Data Sorting

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-order-by, metadata

Essentially I have some user generated meta data for individual items.  Meta data consists of a title and a corresponding value.  One item may have one particular metadata title while another may not.  So, creating a new collumn in my main table seems like the wrong approach, since I don't want every item to have the same meta data titles.

The problem is when I want to sort by that meta data.  I can easily generate a table that makes the metadata look like just another collumn, but I want to sort by that to.  So, to illustrate what I have:

Say I have the following tables:

```
Items Table:
id | color
----------
0  | red
1  | pink
2  | orange

MetaData Table
itemId |     title     |     data
-----------------------------------------
   0        shape           round
   1   |    shape      |    square
   0   |    sound      |    LOUD!
```

I can easily write the SQL and code to generate something like the following from those tables:

```
id  |    color   |   shape    |   sound
--------------------------------------------
0   |    red     |   round    |   LOUD!
1   |    pink    |   square   |            
2   |   orange   |            |
```

So, when generating that, if a item doesn't have a metadata title I'm displaying, then it's just left blank.  I would like to allow the user to sort by shape or sound and just have the ones that are blank show up at the bottom.

I could bring in all the data, generate the tables, then sort it in code..but...that wouldn't be practical at all for hundreds of entries that I may need to work with.

Is this possible to do in SQL (I'm using mysql, but something more generic would be better in case I change that)?  Is my table layout just impractical for this/should I do it a different way (I'd prefer not to change my table layout).

Thanks!

Comment: can you use UNION in your query to generate all records which has meta data and then union it with the records which do not has meta data. but by this approach you will not be able to use order-by clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the blank values at the bottom with something like this:

```
select
  Items.id,
  Items.color,
  max(case when title = 'shape' then data else null end) as shape,
  max(case when title = 'sound' then data else null end) as sound
from Items left outer join MetaData
on Items.id = MetaData.itemId
group by Items.id, Items.color
order by
  case when shape is not null then 0 else 1 end,
  shape
```

Comment: Thanks!  That was exactly what I was looking for and I was a bit unsure how to use aliases and then order by those aliases, so that was also really helpful.

Comment: After trying this out, it seems that you can't use an alias with ORDER BY ... I'll have to keep digging on how to get this to work, but in case someone else reads this..the above SQL won't work for you (at least with Mysql).

Comment: I came up with a solution and posted it as a new solution...I'd love to hear if you have any issues with what I came up with though.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you managed to do that pivot in mysql, I mean, adding `shape` as a column in a query, then you are using a `CASE` or `IF` statement.

So the only thing you need to do is to assign an alias to them and then order by that alias.

That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with Steve Kass's solution.  Anyway, after a bit more reading on pivot tables and some experimentation, here's my working solution for anyone who is interested:

```
SELECT DISTINCT items.id, items.color, 
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN metaData.title = ? THEN metaData.data ELSE NULL END) AS metaDataSortItem FROM items 
LEFT OUTER JOIN metaData ON items.id=metaData.itemId 
GROUP BY items.id
ORDER BY metaDataSortItem ASC
```

It seems to work how I expected it to work.